# Phonegap use Play Services for Ads

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services

With Google phasing out the dedicated Admob SDK in favour of the Play Services SDK how can I integrate ads into my Phonegap app with Play Services? Soon Admob SDK apps won't even be allowed in the Play Store.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago, but figured I should come back here and answer this incase anyone wonders upon this question. Hopefully I'm including everything needed to get this working.

First you need to be including google-play-services_lib in your project.

Then in your main class (will be something like phoneGapAppName/platforms/android/src/com/ myname/myApp/myApp.java)

Under the cordova import (`import org.apache.cordova.*;`) add:

```
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Then in your main public class (something like `public class myApp extends CordovaActivity`) replace the default code with something like:

```
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")


    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("YOUR_ADD_UNIT_CODE");
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;

    layout.addView(mAdView);
    layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdView.resume();
}
```

You may also have to add something like this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

This is what I did and it works perfectly for me, you will need to adapt this to your own app and figure out some of it on your own, but this is a good starting point.